# how to fetch `{` in java regex?

Tags: regex, string, java-8

given this text:

```
RULE deviceType=IPHONE_DEVICE&ClientVersion>=4.10 { bla1 \ } 
RULE deviceType=ANDROID_DEVICE&ClientVersion>=4.5 { bla2 \ }
```

I want to use java regex to fetch this text:

```
bla1 
bla2
```

I have tried:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)RULE deviceType=ANDROID_DEVICE&ClientVersion>=4.5 \\{(\\w+)\\ \\}(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringMap);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        androidSection = matcher.group(1);
    }
```

but the code returned zero matches.

What am i missing?

Comment: the space after the `{`?

Comment: You are failing because of the space after `{` and the `\ ` after the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex to this:

```
RULE deviceType=\w+&ClientVersion>=[\d.]+\h*\{\h*(\w+)\h*\\\h*}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHiYtI/1)

Using Java use this regex:

```
final String regex =
       "RULE deviceType=\\w+&ClientVersion>=[\\d.]+\\h*\\{\\h*(\\w+)\\h*\\\\\\h*\\}";
```